# Unnecessary spacing within minipage

Tags: spacing, minipage

I am using minipage to create two column. Here is my sample simple code to to demonstrate the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        I am sovon. I finished my master.
    \end{minipage}  
\hfill
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
        I am sovon, I finished my master.
   \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and the output is:

```
I am sovon.  I finished my   I am sovon, I finished my master.
master.
```

The problem is with the unnecessary stretching and putting a extra space after first full-stop in first column. Why is that? how can I avoid that?

Comment: Are you looking for `\raggedright` and possibly `\noindent`?

Comment: yes, \raggedright worked. Actually I did not know that by default, it was full-justified. I have some knowledge lacking about text formatting. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help.  The `\noindent` might be used, prior to the first `minipage`, to prevent it from indenting.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest two things:

1. Use `\raggedright` to avoid the stretched out lines, since default alignment is fully justified.  One could make the whole document ragged, by placing it in the preamble, but here I just place it individually in the affected `minipage`s, allowing the rest of the document to retain the default settings.
2. I applied a `\noindent` prior to the first `minipage`, so that the whole `minipage` was not indented relative to the left margin.

In the MWE, I also added a `showframe` to show the `minipage` position relative to the margins, and added some junk text in `minipage` #2 to show that, indeed, the `\hfill` was working as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
      \raggedright
        I am sovon. I finished my master.
    \end{minipage}  
\hfill
   \begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
     \raggedright
        I am sovon, I finished my master. xxxxxxx xx
   \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why raggedright is not default is beyond me. Had to spend a good chunk of time just to figure out how to do what should be default.

Comment: @JohnGlen I'm sure that LaTeX was envisioned for article & book publishing where full justification is the norm.  Report publication (where right justification is more common) came along for the ride.